# "The scariest thing he can/could be called is the Reaper"

Tags: word-choice, can-modal, could

Example 1

> A: He has been feared and reported by many soldiers on the battlefield.
>
> B: I know this guy. He's quite famous and has been mentioned in many reports. The HQ has given him several codenames. The scariest thing he **can/could** be called is the Reaper.

My interpretation: Both can and could are fine. "Can" means among the names that are already given, the Reaper is the scariest. "Could" means among the names that "might" be called, the Reaper is the scariest.

Example 2

> A: These people are very superstitious. They will be terrified when they see Mike massacring their comrades with modern weapons.
>
> B: Well, the scariest thing he **could** be called is probably the Reaper. (He might be called the Reaper when the battle begins, which is the scariest thing)

My interpretation: "Could" is better than "Can" here. It means the name that might be given to him during the next battle is "the Reaper". Using "can" would make it sound like he's already qualified for several nicknames.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: I don't find your sentences at all natural. "HQ has given him several codenames. The scariest [of those names] is 'The Reaper'". You don't need to say that he could be called by the names that have been given to him.

Comment: Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on something in particular that you are unsure about. Asking "am I correct" isn't an acceptable question.

Comment: I agree it doesn't make a great deal of sense. Is there a reason he can't be called anything scarier than "The Reaper"?